# AVSpeechSynthesizer is not working with Hindi language

Tags: ios, swift, avspeechsynthesizer

Imported AVFoundation, working fine with English string but not working with Hindi string. It’s working when I am changing my iPhone language to Hindi from setting which I don’t want. How can I work this code without changing my iPhone language to Hindi(iPhone language is English)?

Below is my code :

```
let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
var myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "")

override func viewDidLoad() {
      myUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "hi-IN")
      Speak()
}

func speak(){
       self.myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "ऑर्डर स्थिति अपडेट कर दी गई है")
                self.synth.speak(self.myUtterance)
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Solved : I changed a position of a line and its working. I set the language after setting string to **myUtterance**.

```
let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
var myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "")

override func viewDidLoad() {

  Speak()
}

func speak(){
    self.myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "ऑर्डर स्थिति अपडेट कर दी गई है")
    myUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "hi-IN")
    self.synth.speak(self.myUtterance)
}
```